# ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

I'm building Iroha for which i'm running a script for environment setup which is internally calling the docker-compose.yml, where i"m getting the error:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "/home/cdac/iroha/docker/docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 5
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in "/home/cdac/iroha/docker/docker-compose.yml", line 13, column 6
```

docker-compose.yml file is showing below.

```
services:
  node:
    image: hyperledger/iroha:develop-build
    ports:
      - "${IROHA_PORT}:50051"
      - "${DEBUGGER_PORT}:20000"
    environment:
      - IROHA_POSTGRES_HOST=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_postgres_1
      - IROHA_POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - IROHA_POSTGRES_USER=iroha
      - IROHA_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=helloworld
      - CCACHE_DIR=/tmp/ccache
     export G_ID=$(id -g $(whoami))
     export U_ID=$(id -g $(whoami))
    user: ${U_ID:-0}:${G_ID:-0}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ../:/opt/iroha
      - ccache-data:/tmp/ccache
    working_dir: /opt/iroha
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=iroha
      - IROHA_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=helloworld
    command: -c 'max_prepared_transactions=100'

volumes:
  ccache-data:
```

any help will be appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are not belongs to the `docker-compose` syntax

```
 export G_ID=$(id -g $(whoami))
 export U_ID=$(id -g $(whoami))
```

Also this line wont be able to work as expected

```
user: ${U_ID:-0}:${G_ID:-0}
```

You should write your own shell script and use it as an entry point for the docker container (this should be done in the `Dockerfile` step) then run a container directly from the image that you have created without the need to assign a user or export anything within the `docker-compose` as it will be executed once your container is running.

Check the following URL which contains more explanation about the allowed keywords in `docker-compose`: [Compose File: Service Configuration Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference)

Answer (score 0):

@MostafaHussein I removed the above 3 lines then executed the run-iroha-dev.sh script, and it started to work. it attached me to /opt/iroha in docker container and downloaded hyperledger/iroha:develop-build and iroha images and launched two containers.
is it same what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes, you need to remove them and if you need them then you can add them as environment variable. If this answers your question mark it as answered. Note that it would be better if you add your comments as a comment below the answer itself so who answered you will get a notification with your comment and so on.

Comment: Sorry for being late, whatever you suggested is working for me, Thank you for helping me to resolve this issue.